# Python add() function of set in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have come across the below code to remove duplicates from a list:

```
seen = set(); print [i for i in list if i not in seen and not seen.add(i)]
```

I could not comprehend what exactly "**and not seen.add(i)**" this part of code is doing as **help(set.add)** gives below explanation:

```
add(...)
    Add an element to a set.
    This has no effect if the element is already present.
```

Looking forward to your help in understanding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension iterates over the values of the original/input list. We want a value to be added to the new/output list if and only if it has not already been seen, hence the conditional expression `if i not in seen`. When a new value is added to the new/output list, the `seen` set has to be updated, hence the `seen.add(i)` function call. However the `set.add()` method returns `None`, which evaluates to `False`. Therefore the `not` operator is added, so that `not seen.add(i)` always returns `True`.

Comment: Awesome! thank you very much.
I also got an understanding that and operator also acts like conditional statement's true part short-circuit behavior